# Counting unique pairs of data R

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

I have a following data set

```
data1 = data.frame("Element" = sample(c(1:100), 600, replace = T))
data1$Factor2 = sample(c("E", "F", "G"), 600, replace = T)
```

I'd like to count the number of Elemens that got matched with each factor from Factor2.
For example, an output could like like the following table:

Factor Number of elements

```
E     45
F     67
G     34
```

which would mean there are 45 distinct rows such as: E,1;E11;E:20. Although row E,1 appears more times, I am not interested in how many times each combination appears, I am interested in how many unique combinations there were.

Comment: Try with `table(data1$Factor2)`  It is better to create example with a specific seed

Comment: `summary(factor(data1$Factor2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    count(Factor2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique` to get the distinct rows and then just create a table of how many times each factor occurred.   I am setting the seed to make the data reproducible.

```
set.seed(2018)
data1 = data.frame("Element" = sample(c(1:100), 600, replace = T))
data1$Factor2 = sample(c("E", "F", "G"), 600, replace = T)

table(unique(data1)$Factor2)
 E  F  G 
85 92 79
```